# Symfony 4 - Problem to position my buttons

Tags: jquery, symfony, collections

I use the jQuery collection plugin : https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/
to manage my groups.

For the moment I've :

[image]

And I would like that my buttons go at the same row that my fields, like this :

[image]

But I do not understand why it does not work. My twig is :

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}

{% form_theme form 
    'partials/jqueryCollection/jquery.collection.html.twig'
     %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="validateurs">
        {{form_start(form)}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{form_widget(form.validateurs, {'attr': {'class': 'my-selector'} })}}
            </div>

        </div>
        {{form_end(form)}}
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="/js/jquery.collection.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.my-selector').collection({
            up: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default ml-2" title="Remonter"><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-lg"></i></span></a>',
            down: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default ml-2" title="Redescendre"><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-lg"></span></a>',
            add: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default ml-2" title="Ajouter"><span><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i></span></a>',
            remove: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default ml-2" title="Supprimer"><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></span></a>',
            position_field_selector: '.my-position',
            add_at_the_end: true
        });
    </script>


{% endblock %}
```

I tried this :

```
<div class="validateurs">
        {{form_start(form)}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{form_widget(form.validateurs, {'attr': {'class': 'my-selector'} })}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="collection-add btn btn-default ml-2" title="Ajouter"><span><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i></span></a>
                {#  other buttons ... #}
            </div>

        </div>
        {{form_end(form)}}
    </div>
```

But it doesn't work

EDIT :

More info :

If I remove the select2() using, I've :

I have the same thing as when I use it, without the function provided by the select2 (). In HTML, I've :

[image]

Code :

```
<div
  id="groupe_validateurs_validateurs"
  class="my-selector ui-sortable"
  data-prototype="<fieldset class="
  data-prototype-name="__name__"
  data-allow-add="1"
  data-allow-remove="1"
  data-name-prefix="groupe_validateurs[validateurs]"
>
  <fieldset
    class="form-group"
    id="groupe_validateurs_validateurs_0_02119825414713091"
    style=""
  >
    <div id="groupe_validateurs_validateurs_0">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select
          id="groupe_validateurs_validateurs_0_validateur"
          name="groupe_validateurs[validateurs][0][validateur]"
          required="required"
          class="js-example-basic-single form-control"
          ><option value="" selected="selected"
            >Sélectionnez un utilisateur</option
          ><option value="1">Admin</option
          ><option value="2">DRH DRH</option
          ><option value="3">Donnelly ARMAND</option
          ><option value="4">Ondricka BLAISE</option
          ><option value="5">Bahringer ITZEL</option
          ><option value="6">Hegmann DON</option
          ><option value="7">Mueller JOAQUIN</option
          ><option value="8">Tillman WILLIE</option
          ><option value="9">Graham PALMA</option
          ><option value="10">Farrell LIANA</option
          ><option value="11">Flatley QUINCY</option
          ><option value="12">Pollich KENNITH</option></select
        >
      </div>
      <input
        type="hidden"
        id="groupe_validateurs_validateurs_0_ordre"
        name="groupe_validateurs[validateurs][0][ordre]"
        class="my-position"
        value="0"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-actions">
      <a
        href="#"
        class="btn btn-default ml-2 groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-remove groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-action"
        title="Supprimer"
        ><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></span></a
      ><a
        href="#"
        class="btn btn-default ml-2 groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-up groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-action-disabled groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-action"
        title="Remonter"
        style="display: none;"
        ><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-lg"></i></span></a
      ><a
        href="#"
        class="btn btn-default ml-2 groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-down groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-action-disabled groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-action"
        title="Redescendre"
        style="display: none;"
        ><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-lg"></i></span
      ></a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <span class="groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-tmp"></span
  ><a
    href="#"
    class="btn btn-default ml-2 groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-action groupe_validateurs_validateurs-collection-rescue-add"
    title="Ajouter"
    ><span><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i></span
  ></a>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the generated HTML for the form look like? Please add this to the question. It's not possible to debug your issue just from a set of pictures. It's very likely that this behavior is caused by the select2 / `<select>` fields being block elements.

Comment: Further: How does the form look if you remove select2's css and js? Does it render correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will update my first post with more info

Comment: Please don't post code in form of screenshots on stackoverflow. Instead copy the code and add it as a code-block.

Comment: Okay sorry, I updated my post